# How can I update the selected state of a ListTile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a Flutter app that displays a list of recordings using ListTile widgets. I'm trying to update the selected state of the ListTile when the user taps on it, but the UI is not updating as expected.

Here is a part of the code I'm using:

```
  Container buildPhraseCard(PhraseCard phrase) {

    int _selectedIndex = 0;

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 32,
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text(
              phrase.phrase,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              ),
            ),
            trailing: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.closed_caption_disabled)),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text("お手本を再生"),
            leading: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.hearing)),
          ),
          Divider(),
          Column(
            children: phrase.userPath.values.toList().asMap().entries.map((entry) {
              final index = entry.key;
              final phrase = entry.value;
              return ListTile(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = index;
                  });
                },
                selected: index == _selectedIndex,
                title: Text("${index + 1}回目の発音"),
                leading: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow)),
                trailing: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.feedback)),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: const Text("3回目を録音"),
            leading: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.mic)),
          ),
          Divider(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 24,
          ),
          Text(
            '総合スコア',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          ),
          Text(
            phrase.userPath.values.elementAt(_selectedIndex).toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 80,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I tap on a ListTile, the _selectedIndex variable is updated and I can see the updated value printed in the console using print(), but the selected state of the ListTile is not changing. How can I update the selected state of the ListTile so that it reflects the _selectedIndex variable?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It worked! Thank so much you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

your variable should be outside of the method because the method is called every time you call the set state and the selected index is set to zero again.

```
 int _selectedIndex = 0;
 Container buildPhraseCard(PhraseCard phrase) {

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      ...
```